# Getting a specific value via index for a JSON object?

Tags: json

I've been trying to use a particular field of a JSON object.

When I use:

```
console.log(item);
```

Results:

```
[{"userid":"111","username":"","usertype":"0","emailaddress":"","phonenumber":"","faxnumber":"","cellnumber":"","gender":"5","race":"1","country":"1"}]
```

When I use:

```
console.log(item.userid);
```

Results:

```
undefined
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to iterate over the array  and then get the particular item

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
 for(var i=o;i<item.length;i++)
 {
  console.log(item[i].userid);
 }
```

Comment: Now I am getting: `(305) undefined`

Comment: If I use this: `for(var i=0;i<item.length;i++){console.log(item[i]);}` I get a log of each individual character of the json object...ie. [, { , " , u , s, e, r, i, d...

Comment: just try once console.log(item[0].userid);

Comment: My apologies the problem was that in the ajax request I used `datatype: 'JSON'` I should have used `dataType`...My mistake